# Search a range of cells for certain string and replace

Tags: excel, vba, macros

I am wanting to search a range of cells for some certain string values and replace them with something else.  At the moment I am trying to just check one column range from AS22 to ??

What I want to search for is:

```
Green
Amber
Red
```

And replace with:

```
On Track
Minor Variance
Major Variance
```

This is the code I have so far, but it is not working and I don't receive any errors - Not sure what wrong.

```
Dim i As Variant
Dim k As Variant
    i = ("Green, Amber, Red")
    k = ("On Track, Minor Variance, Major Variance")
    Columns("AS").Replace What:=i, Replacement:=k, lookat:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False
```

ideally I would like to search columns AS, AT, AU at once and not have to duplicate the code three times.

Can anyone shed some light on the the reason why this code will not  work

Comment: Why are you looking at `xlPart`? Do you want to replace `Stored` with `StoMajor Variance`?

Comment: It was a solution I found in a Google search, had tried a few things and couldn't get it to work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider:

```
Sub qwerty()
        With Range("AS:AU")
            .Replace what:="Green", Replacement:="On Track"
            .Replace what:="Amber", Replacement:="Minor Variance"
            .Replace what:="Red", Replacement:="Major Variance"
        End With
End Sub
```

Comment: thank you, that is a much simpler solution. It works really well

Answer (score 2):

Assign the values as arrays into the respective variant variables then cycle through them using the [LBound function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9a7w1ac(v=vs.90).aspx) and [UBound function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278658.aspx) to define the scope.

```
Dim i As Variant, k As Variant, w As Long

i = Array("Green", "Amber", "Red")
k = Array("On Track", "Minor Variance", "Major Variance")

With Worksheets("Sheet1")    '<~~you should know what worksheet you are on~
    For w = LBound(i) To UBound(i)
        .Columns(45).Replace what:=i(w), replacement:=k(w), _
                       lookat:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False
    Next w
End With
```

Subject to my comment above, I've replaced your `lookat:=xlPart` with `lookat:=xlWhole`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim fndList As Variant
Dim rplcList As Variant
Dim x As Long

fndList = Array("Red", "Amber", "Green")
rplcList = Array("On track", "Minor Variance", "Minor Variance")

'Loop through each item in Array lists
  For x = LBound(fndList) To UBound(fndList)
    'Loop through each worksheet in ActiveWorkbook
      For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        sht.Cells.Replace What:=fndList(x), Replacement:=rplcList(x), _
          LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, _
          SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
      Next sht

  Next x
```